# Assign a value to the variable inside the array with VB.NET in WinForms

Tags: string, winforms, vb.net-2010

I am doing windows application in vb.net. I want to assign a value to the variable at run time.

For example.

```
Dim Mystring(2) As String
Mystring(0) = "1"
Mystring(1) = "2"
Dim var1, var2 As String
Mystring = {a = Mystring(0), b = Mystring(1)}
MsgBox(var1)
MsgBox(var2)
```

I want to store the **Mystring(0)** value in variable **var1** and **Mystring(1)** value in variable **var2**, but the above code message box returns null value. Thanks!

Comment: Those are not assignments, the = operator test for equality.   You are initializing the array elements with *Booleans*.   Use Option Strict On to let the compiler help you write correct code.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Passant. yes its returns booleans as result. Is there any way to assign directly inside the array elements. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a list of string objects.

```
Dim Mystring As New List(Of String)
```

Second, add two string values in the list.

```
Mystring.Add("1")
Mystring.Add("2")
```

Third, declare two new variables of type string.

```
Dim var1, var2 As String
```

Fourth, assign the first and second values of the list of string objects to the newly created variables of type string.

```
var1 = Mystring(0)
var2 = Mystring(1)
```

Finally, show each value in a message box.

```
MsgBox(var1)
MsgBox(var2)
```

Comment: thanks @Ivaylo Petrov. but is it possible to assign the value directly `Mystring = {a = Mystring(0), b = Mystring(1)}` like this. Because in my windows application my string size is big. By doing like above you mentioned i want to write many lines of code, so i want reduce lines of code.

Comment: You can add new values to list of string like this: `Dim list As New List(Of String)(New String() {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"})`

Comment: Also you do not need to assign each of this values to new variable, in order to show it in a message box. You can show it just like that: `MsgBox(Mystring(0))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an array your code should look like this, though the advice to use List is good.

```
    Dim Mystring(1) As String
    Mystring(0) = "1"
    Mystring(1) = "2"
    Dim var1, var2 As String
    var1 = Mystring(0)
    var2 = Mystring(1)
```

I changed the declaration of the array.  The number in the () is the highest index, one less than the number of items needed.  Remeber we are starting at 0 for indices.